# How can I distinguish between Holidays and Birthdays and user created all day events

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-contentresolver

I'm am working on an app that gets all the user events and calendars to the app.
But I wish to distinguish between an user created all day event, and one that was automatically added to the calendar like a birthday or a holiday.

I get all the different calendars like this:

```
cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
            (new String[]{Calendars._ID, Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL}), null, null, null);
```

and the events like this:

```
Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                new String[]{"title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "(" + Events.CALENDAR_ID + " = ?)",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(userCalendar.id)}, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC");
```

In addition, can someone please direct me to the list of available google calendar and event fields?
for some reason I couldn't find them anywhere...

Thanks

Comment: if u solved it, give ur answer here

Comment: never had the chance to get back to it... I posted a semi answer already below.
better then nothing...

Comment: i actually i found a work around, not that effective but , i will share it as an answer. for others

Answer (score 0):

well for now I'm just filtering out according to the access level

```
 if (userCalendar.accessLevel != Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_READ)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly, distinguish the events as birthdays , holidays or user created Events.
But I did a workaround, its for my app [LinkedOut](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rectfy.linkedout) Which organize contacts based on the events. So i want only the actual events not birthdays.

So I only took the events which have locations, because , the kind of events what i want will have locations.

If you only want birthdays, filter the events which contain "birthday" in the event name, 
all the other event, which do not have location and do not have 'birthday' in their name will be holidays.

I know it may not be always correct , but it will work for now.

Code for getting events that has location,

```
public void getDataFromEventTable() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR}, 121);
    }
    Cursor cur = null;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    String[] mProjection =
            {
                    "_id",
                    CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
                    CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
                    CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
            };

    Uri uri = CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;

    cur = cr.query(uri, mProjection, null, null, null);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        String title = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE));
        String loc = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION));
        if(loc.length()>0)
            Log.e("event",title+" "+loc);
    }

}
```